# Update MariaDB to 10.6.7 XAMPP Mac OS

Tags: php, mariadb, xampp, moodle

I'm using mac M1. I want install moodle on xampp so I can't run it because XAMPP has MariaDB version 10.4.28 and moodle requires 10.6.7. I couldn't find any XAMPP Version on the official website with mariaDB version 10.6.7. Any Solutions?

Comment: You can always upgrade mariadb separately or install a standalone instance of it without xampp

Comment: you need to wait till apachefriends update their package, or stop the server and install a separate instance

Comment: Choose the lastest 10.6 version. 10.6.7 has a lot of bugs that have been fixed in later versions. [Packages are available](https://mariadb.org/download/?t=mariadb&p=mariadb&r=10.6.16&os=windows&cpu=x86_64&pkg=msi).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use MAMP instead of XAMPP

I think MAMP was originally designed for Mac

https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/

There are ready made packages available for Mac which include Moodle and MAMP

https://docs.moodle.org/403/en/Installation_Package_for_macOS

Downloads are here

https://download.moodle.org/macosx/